# PHP mail formatting issue - Why do CRLF header line endings break HTML email in Outlook?

Tags: php, mime, postfix-mta, html-email, email-formats

I'm using the PHP native `mail()` function to send HTML emails and have a formatting problem in the users most common email client - **Outlook 2007** (*in addition to some other email clients*) - all the html tags are exposed so it looks like gibberish to a non-web-developer.

I'm sending HTML email the same way that the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) demos it. Example:

```
$message  = get_HTML_email_with_valid_formatting();
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: example.com <info@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: donotreply@example.com\r\n";
mail('me@example.com', 'test', $message, $headers);
```

Because testing various email clients is hard, I have signed up with http://litmusapp.com/ so I can see a screenshot of the emails in 47 different email clients. Most are ok (e.g. gmail, thunderbird, Lotus Notes) but all the different versions of Outlook are not ok.

To fix the formatting issue I had do the following:

1. Remove the `$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";` mail header.
2. Ensure I end my headers with only "`\n`" instead of "`\r\n`".

Does anyone know why I am getting better results with HTML emails when I do not conform to the manual?

Info:

- I'm using [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) version 2.3.3 on RHEL 5.5.
- PHP version 5.3.2

Comment: "I'm using the PHP native mail() function to send HTML emails" - well, there's your problem* ;-) Have you considered using something like e.g. http://swiftmailer.org ? | * _maybe_ not the mail() function itself but the combination of mail(), some string concatenation & trying to solve the protocol and the application level problem at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

1. Upgrade Postfix to +2.9 which has "sendmail_fix_line_endings" (finally!!!) See: [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html)
2. Install Sendmail (working fine!)

I have a VMware image with a LAMP stack. In order to send email, I finally decided to:

- install Sendmail
- use the smtp of my ISP (as it is only a dev box).

For the sendmail part, you can follow this: http://www.geoffke.be/nieuws/13/

**IMPORTANT**: Some webhosters may use only stable packages which means you can have... a Postfix older than 2.9!!! Exemple: http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=postfix

Answer (score 4):

If You use postfix<2.9, You can just put `sendmail_path = "tr -d '\r'|sendmail -t -i"` into php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is my version of Postfix - version 2.3.3 is **5 years old** and perhaps it is converting LF to CRLF but seeing as I had CRLF already, I think I was sending CRCRLF to the mail clients.

Unfortunately, I'm not in the situation to upgrade Postfix. So for the moment I have converted the code to use a configurable variable for the line endings so that it is easy to change in the future:

```
$eol = "\n";
$message  = get_HTML_email_with_valid_formatting();
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8".$eol;
$headers .= "From: example.com <info@example.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "Reply-To: donotreply@example.com".$eol;
mail('me@example.com', 'test', $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score -1):

The email is been interpreted as text/plain instead of intended html. The reason for this is that **text/html** is a multipart subtype thus requiring boundary declarations.

Your code is missing a the **header boundary** declaration:

```
$message  = get_HTML_email_with_valid_formatting();
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "--$boundary\r\n"."Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: example.com <info@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: donotreply@example.com\r\n";
mail('me@example.com', 'test', $message, $headers);
```

Check this wiki about MIME & Multipart Messages:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

Comment: ...so that the result is at least consistent in that _all_ email clients will display junk?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was under the impression that HTML emails don't strictly need to be multipart. i.e. having a text version is good practice but not required.