# Php Mail() email sent to Comcast.net Address POP3ed to Outlook not displaying HTML Format

Tags: php, email

This is sort of a complex issue, hopefully you can help.

I am using php mail() to send an HTML formatted email of blog content (an "email to a friend" option sends post content to a user supplied email address).

I am having an issue with Comcast.net email addresses.

The HTML formatted email comes through correctly when viewed on Comcast.com's internet mail, but when POP3ing it to outlook, the html format is stripped and the user gets only the html code.

So, when an HTML formatted email is sent to a comcast.net address and then pulled to outlook via POP3 the HTML format is stripped and only displays the html code.

One interesting thing to note it that when viewing the email on Comcast.com's mail viewer the from line is present, but after being pulled into Outlook the from line is blank.

I have tested this with other accounts, gmail, aol, yahoo, and these all POP3 to outlook correctly, it is specific to Comcast.

Anyone have any ideas why this would be happening?

[UPDATE]

I removed the "\r" from the header information ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449431/php-mail-formatting-issue-why-do-crlf-header-line-endings-break-html-email-in-o)) and it corrected the format issue

Can anyone shed light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the "\r" from the header information ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449431/php-mail-formatting-issue-why-do-crlf-header-line-endings-break-html-email-in-o)) and it corrected the format issue.

Hope this helps everyone.