# sending mail from php: headers are interpreted as body?

Tags: php, email

When I send mail from php with \r\n as line break in the headers ([as it should be according to documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415654/which-line-break-in-php-mail-header-r-n-or-n))

```
$headers = "From: $email\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To:  Just me <$email>\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
$subject = "Hello world";
$body = "<html><p>Hey, whats up?</p></html>";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Some mail clients will interpret \r\n as being two line breaks. So for this mail() above the real mail content would look like this:

```
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0LEdMMtPAYT0xO0Q9MTtTQ0w9MA==
X-Message-Status: n
Received: from server75.publicompserver.de ([92.43.108.63]) by snt0-mc2-f13.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);
 Thu, 9 Dec 2010 12:09:22 -0800
Message-ID: <40177C.70807@justme.org>
[lots of other headers]
Date: Thu, 09 Dec 2010 21:09:32 +0100
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 09 Dec 2010 20:09:22.0873 (UTC) FILETIME=[F88C3A90:01CB97DC]
From: $email

Reply-To:  Just me <$email>

Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<html><p>Hey, whats up?</p></html>
```

Now some clients (googlemail for example) will ignore these extra linebreaks. Others (thunderbird) will interpret the first extra linebreak as being the end of the headers and will interpret the rest of the header lines as being part of the body (losing header information, in this case rendering the mail as text instead of html).

I've seen the same problem from other mail-sending websites, too.

What is happening here? \r\n is the correct line break according to doc, or is something else going wrong here?
And how can it be resolved? Changing the line break to \n instead of \r\n seems to help, but since the docs say "thou should use \r\n" this can't be right, can it?

Comment: In your previous question I mentioned the `PHP_EOL` constant. Did you try it with this?

Comment: Since these scripts are running on Apache/Unix, PHP_EOL would be \n, not?

Comment: Maybe someone can shed some light on exactly how the unix sendmail script transforms `\n` to `\r\n`

Comment: You're not being consistent in your example with your usage of `\r\n`. Some of your headers are terminated with CRLF, some with just LF.

Comment: @Thanatos, yep, sorry, I whipped the example up from different sources since I didn't want it to contain real email adresses. Corrected now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is mentioned in the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php: "If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some poor quality Unix mail transfer agents replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822."

So, as you said: it's not right, but it's reality.

Comment: So I should use \r\n until one of the mail receivers complain, than switch to \n instead? But how can I be sure they complain (especially if the reply-header is lost) so I'll notice and not just delete the message?

Comment: my guess would be that for greatest compatibility, use \n only, RFC be damned, as long as your testing shows no problems with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your previous question. Each platform delimits lines in a different way (CRLF or LF). It's best to leave this decision up to PHP via the `PHP_EOL` constant and PHP will take care of it.

Comment: PHP_EOL is just a different writing for \n on unix platforms, and all these scripts run on unix systems, so you'd say I should ignore RFC 2822 and go with \n instead?

Comment: This comment in the documentation sheds some light: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#100563

Comment: This comment about \r\n being changed to \r\r\n sheds some light on the problem: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#100193

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're using \r\n for some of the header lines, and only \n for others. Maybe this problem wouldn't occur if you were consistent.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is not the real code, this is just some sample I whipped up on the fly - the code itself is consistent, my mistake!