# PHP mail() Not displaying HTML

Tags: php, email, plesk

We've recently upgraded to a Plesk Parallel Linux Server and it appears as if the PHP settings are ignoring headers! The emails are receiving fine, but *display* the HTML tags.

The `phpInfo()` file can be viewed here: https://www.pressgofer.com/phpInfo.php

The PHP itself should be okay, but have included it here anyway.

**PHP Mail Code**

```
$email = "example@example.com";
$message = "<h1 style='font-family:Helvetica,Arial;font-size:17px'>Your account has a password reset request</h1>";

$headers = "From: noreply@pressgofer.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:  noreply@pressgofer.com \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($email, "Reset password notification", $message, $headers);
```

Many thanks,
Nick

Comment: Try `mime` and `content-type` before message.

Comment: your phpinfo shows that mail.add_x_header is OFF. you need to turn it on.

Comment: @Renku that wouldn't make any difference- both variables are passed into the `mail()` function at the same time. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

your `phpinfo` shows that `mail.add_x_header` is OFF. you need to turn it on

To enable the `X-Mail` header, set `mail.add_x_header` to 1 in your `php.ini`

```
<?php
$to = "yourplace@somewhere.com";
$subject = "My HTML email test.";
$headers = "From: sinha.ksaurabh@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: sinha.ksaurabh@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: sinha.ksaurabh@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "<h1> This is a test </h1>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
   echo "The email has been sent!";
   } else {
   echo "The email has failed!";
   }
?>
```

Comment: yes there may be permission problem on php.ini file. try to copy the file to your desktop and then access it to search the term "mail.add_x_header"

Comment: Okay, the `phpInfo()` now registers `mail.add_x_header` as ON. It is still producing HTML tags as visible

Comment: @Nick: :) OK, no Issues. Let me see what else I can do with it.

Comment: Many thanks! :-) Am just restarting the server to see if it updates PHP configs after. 

__No difference.__

Comment: @Nick: I have added a small script to the answer. Please try to execute that on your server. See if it sends email in correct format

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26625/discussion-between-nick-price-and-saurabh-sinha)

Answer (score 0):

[sending mail from php: headers are interpreted as body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415786/sending-mail-from-php-headers-are-interpreted-as-body)

Issue was associated with MIME type and server interpretation- no `\r` needed.