# Sending HTML email with PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send an html email with PHP and it keeps coming just as text. All of the values are generated correctly from the php it is just text in the email. Here is the code:

```
    $to='xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com';
    $from = 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
    $subject = "Print Run: " . $run . " is ordered";
    $body ="<html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Date Added</th>
                    <th>
                    </th>
                </tr>";
            for($i = 0; $i < $arraySize; $i++){     
                $body .= "<tr><td>" . $companyName[$i] . "</td><td>" . $quantity[$i] . "</td><td>" . $cardSize[$i] . "</td><td>" . $dateAdded[$i] . "</td></tr>";
            }
            $body .= "<tr>
                        <td style=\"font-weight:bold; border-style:solid; border-top-width:1px;\">Totals</td>
                        <td style=\"font-weight:bold; border-style:solid; border-top-width:1px;\">" . $totals . "</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </body>
                        </html>";

    mail($to,"Print Run: " . $run . " is ordered",$body,$headers);
```

Comment: did you check if it's not caused by your email client settings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You overwrite the header on the last of the three lines:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = "From: $from \r\n";
```

Should be (note the dot):

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from \r\n";
```

Comment: Wasn't so hard to discover it, really :)

Comment: One other gotcha i've seen is the "\r\n".  This will fail on some systems and should be replaced with PHP_EOL.

Comment: @Matt H: Your comment is misleading, you should back that up with the RFC and PHP source-code. `"\r\n"` is absolutely correct, see as well [Which line break in php mail header, \r\n or \n?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4415654/367456).