# Apache resets "Return-Path: " to <nobody@server.com> in PHP's mail() function

Tags: php, email, return-path

The following headers are sent using PHP's mail() function:

```
$emailheaders = "From: " . $sender . "\n";
$emailheaders .= "Return-Path: " . $sender . "\n";
$emailheaders .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$emailheaders .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

mail($email, $subject, $body, $emailheaders);
```

It works fine, except `Return-Path:` is reset to `nobody@server.com`, or at least this is what shows up when viewing extended headers for emails received using the above headers. Naturally this means that bounce emails are not received.

Does Apache reset the headers, and in this case why, or am I using `mail()` incorrectly?

What can I do to prevent this from happening. Using `mail()`'s fifth parameter (e.g. `-f sender@server.com`) is out of the question as PHP is in safe mode and the provider will not change that. I suppose that there isn't some way to allow the fifth parameter for certain users despite safe mode being on.

The server is running Apache 2.2.3 and PHP version 5.1.6.

Comment: Can you also add the field `Reply-To` and see what happens? And you're now mixing '\n' and '\r\n'. Most php mail examples use "\r\n", so you might want to fix that first.

Comment: adding reply-to does not change things. Regarding the missing "\r" please see post below.

Answer (score 2):

The server's Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) is overriding the `return-path`. For example if using Exim:

Set the `return-path` in the `/etc/exim/exim.conf` configuration file:

```
return_path = sender@example.com
```

If you don't have access to the server config or the `mail()` fifth parameter then there's probably nothing you can do.

Comment: Well I might be able to convince the host to change it. However I have very little experience with dealing with Apache/server settings so I wouldn't know where to begin. But, if I did suggest a viable solution to the web host they might just do it. What do you suggest should be in the exim.conf file instead?

Comment: If you can ask them to use your e-mail adres as a fixed return-path, then you probably can ask them to run php in non-safe mode. Let them read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) so they understand that they should change their shared server infrastructure

Comment: @Matte they could be using any other MTA such as sendmail so I wouldn't suggest config changes to the host, just tell them what you want to achieve - ie tell them you want your email address as the `return-path` and that you can't do it yourself because it's part of the MTA config.

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the headers using `\n` but according to PHP it should be \r\n (see [Which line break in php mail header, \r\n or \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415654/which-line-break-in-php-mail-header-r-n-or-n)).

Perhaps thats the reason why the header isnt send correctly.

Comment: Correct you are. However I removed the "\r"s after reading that people had problems using it. So, with other words it does not work with nor with out "\r".