# How to get php mail() to work?

Tags: php, sendmail

My script.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$to      = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: anotheremail@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: anotheremail@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$res = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

php.ini essentials

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
mail.log = /home/myuser/phpmail.log
```

- When I run script.php it takes about 30 seconds before it displays bool(true).
- /home/myuser/phpmail.log contains entry with all headers
- /usr/sbin/sendmail is the correct path to sendmail
- The email does not get through. Tested several different addresses e.g. mailinator

How do I get it to work? What can i do to debug?

Comment: Is your server a trusted sender for `domain.com`?

Comment: first thing i would check are the mail server logs

Comment: Have you checked the sendmail log?

Comment: @Jack depends on what you mean with a trusted sender?
Barmar: yes, nothing weird there i'm afraid. If I'm looking in the right place? /var/log/mail.log

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9575534/2194007) to a related question might be of interest. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you use sendmail? (or exim/postfix providing sendmail look alike) **YES** => Which sendmail version do you use? Do you have `sendmail.cf` and `submit.cf` in `/etc/mail/` ?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip yes, Version 8.14.4. I have sencmail.cf and submit.cf in /etc/mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked

Opened port 25 for localhost in iptables and removing the "i" from sendmail_path in php.ini

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Answer (score 1):

0) Check sendmail log files

1) Send a test message as the same system user

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/sendmail -v -t -i <<END
To: myemail@gmail.com
Subject: the subject
From: anotheremail@domain.com
Reply-To: anotheremail@domain.com

hello
END
echo SENDMAIL EXIT CODE: $?
```

Comment: No errors in senmail logs. That script worked fine, no errors and the email got sent. Why?