# PHP mail headers is not working properly

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I'm sending mails using the PHP mail() function. The mail headers is not working properly.

```
$charset = mb_detect_encoding($message);

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";    
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset='.$charset  . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: php';
```

In the above code, the only first line is parsed and the later 4 lines are showing in the message body. "From" was not set.

```
$charset = mb_detect_encoding($message);

$headers  = 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset='.$charset  . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: php';
```

In the above code, "From" and "MIME" lines are parsed correctly, but the later 3 lines are showing in the message body.

GMail is receiving it correctly.

Comment: Why you mixing single quotes with double quotes ? Use any one.

Comment: try $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Comment: @Rikesh, single or double quotes is not a problem.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi, I've tried with or without charset. Same problem occurred.

Comment: sorry your question is difficult to understand, what headers problem you are facing, what is set for $from?

Comment: What's this obsession with `Reply-To:`? It's only necessary or useful when its value differs from `From:`. Anyway, it seems that Outlook ignores it completely.

Comment: can we see your `mail()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use `\n` only instead of `\r\n`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> Note:
>
> If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.

You may use the code below to easy change of end of line in email:

```
$EEOL = "\n";
$headers  = 'From: '.$from . $EEOL;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $EEOL;
```

Comment: Fantastic! It works. Do you know how can I check to use "\n" or "\r\n"?

Comment: I use a PHP pre-defined constant [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) according to the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4415687/1179841 Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using an email class library instead of the regular mail() function in php.
I personally like the free [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) because of its simplicity and great functions for attachments etc.