# PHP Amazon SES v3 - Missing Required Header 'From'

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have to upgrade my PHP Amazon SES API from version v2 to version v3. The same code I had working in v2 does not working in the v3.

Follow the code:

```
//Send the message (which must be base 64 encoded):
$ses = new SesClient([
    'credentials' => new Credentials(
        $this->connection->getUsername(),
        $this->connection->getPassword()
    ),
    'region' => $this->connection->getServer(),
    'version' => '2010-12-01'
]);

// the body message generated by PHP Mailer:
$message = 
    "Date: Tue, 6 Sep 2016 16:46:35 -0300\n" . 
    "To: some@email.com\n" . 
    "From: my_registered_email@at.amazon.com\n" . 
    "Reply-To: my_registered_email@at.amazon.com\n" . 
    "Subject: Email Subject\n" . 
    "Message-ID: <3a1db7d5ae6b610cab5898f0be4a00a3@machine-id>\n" . 
    "X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.16 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)\n" . 
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . 
    "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n" . 
    "        boundary=\"b1_3a1db7d5ae6b610cab5898f0be4a00a3\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n" . 
    "\n" . 
    "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n" . 
    "\n" . 
    "--b1_3a1db7d5ae6b610cab5898f0be4a00a3\n" . 
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\n" . 
    "\n" . 
    "html text bodyOK\n" . 
    "\n" . 
    "\n" . 
    "--b1_3a1db7d5ae6b610cab5898f0be4a00a3\n" . 
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n" . 
    "\n" . 
    "<h1>html text body</h1>OK\n" . 
    "\n" . 
    "\n" . 
    "\n" . 
    "--b1_3a1db7d5ae6b610cab5898f0be4a00a3--\n";

$ses->sendRawEmail(
    [
        'RawMessage' => [
            'Data' => base64_encode($message),
        ]
    ]
);
```

When I run the code I got the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException' with message 'Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameterValue (client): Missing required header 'From'. - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Missing required header 'From'.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>9ea0eaa9-746a-11e6-a6cb-21af912ef7d9</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
'
```

But this code worked with the API v2.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but [the correct line delimiter for email headers is `\r\n`, not `\n`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4415687/1695906).  Perhaps the old SDK was being overly "helpful?"

Comment: Hey Michael, i tryied to use the delimeter \r\n instead only \n but I got the same message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I digged into the AWS SDK source code and I realize that I do not need to encode the message.

So, I removed the base64_encode function and everything is working now!!

The final code is:

```
(...)
$ses->sendRawEmail(
    [
        'RawMessage' => [
            'Data' => $message,  // <-- Removed base64_encode from here
        ]
    ]
);
```