# Unable to send mail via php using mail() or phpmailer in wamp64

Tags: php, email

I am creating a login page.For that, after the signup I need to send the mail to the user for verification.Therefore, I need to send mail.To send the mail, I tried with mail() function like this,

```
<?php
//sending email with the php mail()
mail('mahadev.3333@gmail.com', 'Subject Line Here', 'Body of Message Here', 'From: vidya.5555@gmail.com');
?>
```

I have configured php.ini file also like below,

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from ="vidya.merahkee@gmail.com"
```

I am using windows 64-bit.

And also I have tried with phpmailer. But,I didn't find any solution.Since, 2 day I am trying this.I am unable to do this one.

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: What sort of error messages or unexpected behavior are you getting? (Also, as an etiquette pointer, [highlighting the urgency of your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) is frowned upon)

Comment: Do you actually have an SMTP server running on your machine? Try running a command prompt (Start Menu > Run > cmd) and then `telnet localhost 25`. Does it connect?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using the script on production server then ask your admin for the mail function is active or not . Some time on production server it's blocked by Site admin.

Second if you are using this script on localhost server means  on your desktop then first you have to use the mail server start.

for example i am considering that you are using XAMMPP on windows then Your have to start the **Mercury Mail Server** From the XAMPP control panel. 
**Mercury** by default comes with **postmaster** and **newuser** two users.

Then You have to download **Mozilla Thunderbird** mail client and configure the 
**newuser** and **postmaster** user in mail client  by following the **Create New account > email**  using the newuser@localhost and manually configure the pop and smtp server and port . usually default ports.

you can use the `sendmail_from ="newuser@localhost"`

then check **Mercury** Mail server is running then test your script.

it will send the mail and you then check it in the **Mozilla Thunderbird** mail client.

**Third** : for setting the `From:` you have to use the `header` like below

`$headers  = "From: newuser < newuser@domain.com >\n";`

```
   <?php
     $send_to      = 'postmaster@localhost';
     $mail_subject = 'Subject of Your mail';
     $message_body = 'Body of your email like message form php script.';
     $headers = 'From: newuser@localhost' . "\r\n";
     mail($send_to, $mail_subject, $message_body, $headers);

  ?>
```

I hope this will solve the problem .

**NOTE** if you want to send email form localhost to gamil or any other mail site then you have to use the **sendmail** application or more tutorial Search the google Term like 'Send email via Gmail in PHP '

Comment: I am using wamp here.

Comment: Not an Issue . if you want fast solution then simply download the XAMPP and stop the apache and mysql in XAMPP and let your wamp server run the Apache and Mysql . 

In XAMPP simply start the **Mercury Mail Server ** Try a test . I hope that will work.

Comment: With send mail application also I have tried. But, still I am facing the same issue. I have referred  the  following video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqm64zHlFUg

Comment: I have a query here,Is it can't be done using  wamp?

Comment: Yep you can do but it will take lots of Configuration and Like installing the seprate mail server and then configure  and if you use the xampp then it simply download it  then install it .... it will save time and error ... later on you can do your hard work.

Comment: I have installed the separate mail server called phpmailer but still  I am getting the same error..If I want to do this with wamp only what all the steps I need to follow

Comment: PHPMailer is not the server its mail script written in php.
Read the phpmailer description  

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170367/discussion-between-vidya-and-er-amit-joshi).

Comment: I have as below it is working fine: -

Comment: 1.In xampp/sendmail/sendmail.ini file, edit these lines [sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=xxx.xxxx@gmail.com
auth_password=xxx@123

Comment: 2.And in  xampp/php/php.ini file edit these lines,[mail function]

SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = xxx.xxxx@gmail.com
sendmail_path ="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header = On

Comment: 3.And after editing restart xampp-control panel

Comment: Thanks For Update

Comment: 4. In php, $message="Check mail";
$headers="From:xxx.xxxx@gmail.com";
mail("user.@gmail.com","Testing",$message,$headers);
echo "mail has sent";

Comment: don't forget to use ` "\r\n"`  or line break.
 
Read below post for good clearification
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415687/9128487

Comment: Thanks 
**Thumbs Up**
Finally issue closed. :)

Comment: Thank you Er.Amit Joshi for assisting me :)