# The e-mail header from the online form is displayed incorrectly

Tags: php, html-email

I have a questionnaire form on the web. After filling in this form, I send it to me by email, using the PHP function `mail()`. The form body and the data it contains, including the private message are displayed correctly on **gmail.com**. The problem, however, occurs in the header of the email itself. Some characters are displayed incorrectly.
Here is a sample header:

```
$headers = "Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From:" .$email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply:" . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion() . "\r\n" ;
```

Required display of email subject:

```
Nový dotaz -- námět, od Fořt Petr <p.fort1990@gmail.com>
```

Simultaneous displaying of the subject:

```
NovÃ½ dotaz -- nÃ¡mÄ☒t od: FoÅ☒t Petr <p.fort1990@gmail.com>
```

The squared times symbol is more like a rectangle.

Is anything wrong? Or where should I look for a mistake?

Comment: typo: `$headerd .=` should be `$headers .=`

Comment: it was a keystroke next door.

Comment: Please provide an example of characters which are displayed incorrectly. What is the expected output? Are they in the utf-8 charset?

Comment: 1) php version ?   
2) Does your html page contains <meta charset = "UTF-8"> in the header section?   
3) Does your form use the attribute accept-charset="xxxxxx" and what is the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure \r\n works on all platforms

see : [Which line break in php mail header, \r\n or \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415654/which-line-break-in-php-mail-header-r-n-or-n)

instead

```
("xxx\r\n\yyy");
```

use

```
Header('xxx');
Header('yyy');
```

or use PHP_EOL, not "\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. My hosting provider uses different character encoding for the headers - I can't explain why, but the following php function will do it all.

```
function recode_to_utf8 ($text, $encoding = "utf-8")
{
    return "=?$encoding?Q?" . imap_8bit($text) . "?=";
}
```

And now all you have to do is send an email using the mail () method in combination with the method defined above  `recode_to_utf8()`. Like this:

```
mail(recode_to_utf8($mail_to), recode_to_utf8($subject), recode_to_utf8($message), recode_to_utf8($headers));
```

I hope it helps others if they have the same problem as me.