# HTML Emails Displaying odd in some clients

Tags: php, html, email, email-headers

I'm using PHP to generate a fancy HTML email to send to visitors, but for some reason certain visitors are saying the HTML isn't working for them (seeing RAW HTML rather than pretty email).

I haven't narrowed it down to a certain client, but having talked to them they say they can receive other HTML emails so it's something I'm doing wrong...

My PHP code is as follows

```
$to = 'jm391@le.ac.uk';
$subject = 'Daily Update - New Bikes Matching Your Alerts';
$headers = "From: john@findthatbike.co.uk\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: john@findthatbike.co.uk\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'Your message has been sent<br/>';
} else {
    echo 'There was a problem sending the email.<br/>';
}
```

And my $message variable is loaded with the below links HTML source

http://www.findthatbike.co.uk/sampleemail.html

My customer forwarded a non working email to me and the forwarded chunk look like the below, I'm told he gets HTML emails from others so really not sure what to try...

```
From: john@findthatbike.co.uk [mailto:john@findthatbike.co.uk] 
Sent: 05 April 2013 08:35
To: XXXXX XXXXX
Subject: Daily Update - New Bikes Matching Your Alerts

Reply-To: john@findthatbike.co.uk

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Message-Id: <20130405073022.8597D9CF79D@MY SERVER ADDRESS>
Date: Fri,  5 Apr 2013 08:30:22 +0100 (BST)
X-invURIBL-Scan: Scanned by invURIBL 3.1.1 on 05/04/2013 08:34:17
X-invURIBL-Weight: 0
X-invURIBL-Range: CLEAN
X-Declude-Sender: MY SERVER NAME [MY SERVER IP]
X-Declude-Spoolname: 72086847.eml
X-Declude-RefID: 
X-MessageStream-Note: Scanned by MessageStream (www.messagestream.com).
X-MessageStream-Scan: Score [0] at 08:34:29 on 05 Apr 2013
X-MessageStream-Tests: Whitelisted
X-Country-Chain: UNITED KINGDOM->destination


        <html>
        <body style="background:url('http://findthatbike.co.uk/images/bg3.jpg') repeat fixed 0 0 #EEEEEE; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
```

Comment: What's the error they are getting? or which part isn't working? Sometimes if the sender is not in the safe list certain things like links, images...etc doesn't show up in emails...

Comment: Sorry should of been clearer they are simply seeing the raw code not a nice pretty HTML email. I've added that, and also a copy the forwarded email the custoemr gave me...

Comment: Notice the double line breaks between your headers. A quick search leads to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449431/ and some related links.

Comment: with which email client this issue occurs? I.e. Hotmail has a view source option which allows clients to see raw html output instead of html...

Comment: Thanks solved it, I also noticed many people saying the PHP mail function isn't good and to use phpmailer class instead so I moved over to that and it works without any messing around with headers.